# How does a recirculation valve used with tankless water heaters work?

Tags: plumbing, valve, tankless

I understand that a recirculation valve will push cold water into the cold line from the hot line, until the water reaches a certain temperature in the hot line.

But curious how does it do it? What is the mechanism for this? And if you know, do you recommend its use with a recirculation pump system? If so, is only one per heater is installed at the furthest faucet, or one per faucet/point of use?

Thank you.

[image: NPE-A series tankless water heaters circ valve]

Comment: Do you have the configuration to set this up? It requires a pressure drop across the heater, I think a better method would be to use a small tanked water heater inline to do the recirculating because the huge heat exchanger kicking on for a gallon or so of water will actually waste energy. But it can be set up with multiple check valves. Or use an in line heater close to the point of use.

Comment: I dont. I just got a tankless heater, and was thinking of adding this. My unit has a re circulation pump. That is the pressure drop, right?
And yes, I see your point an adding another small unit...

Comment: Each manufacturer is different so you will need there specifications to set it up.

Comment: I can see a lot of problems with recirc systems if the unit has a check valve to prevent reverse flow from the unit into the water main.

Comment: We have a gas fired tankless water heater. It has internal controls which respond to water flow rate. I cannot imagine combining this with a recirculation system.

Comment: @JimStewart, what do you mean? This valve is made for a tankless system, https://www.navieninc.com/accessories/navicirc.

Comment: If your tankless WH is a model specifically designed for recirculation, then I stand corrected. Does your tankless WH have built in recirc pump?

Comment: I see the distinction, thank you. And yes, mine does. I will add this to the question.